# the proper way to release UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

after asking question about Instruments and finding problems with my code there are two questions:

1st: Why the code above shows in Allocation Instrument exactly what I need?(The memory allocated is less than 30 Mb)

```
NSMutableArray* arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:30];
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture%d",i] ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img];
    [img release];
}
imageView.animationImages = arrayOfImages;
[arrayOfImages release];
....
imageView.animationImages = nil;
[imageView release];
```

But on the fact, there are more memory allocated.

According to the developer documentation(Memory Management) I suppose I do everything correct, but on the device program usually crashesh due to the lack of memory. Of course, this is not the full code, but the problem is definetely here.(in application there are 5 UIImageViews with animations and all of them use too much memory.)

**EDIT** Okay, is it somehow possible to resolve such problem. With memory problems using UIImages?

Comment: Could it be that you're just allocating too much, that the device just runs out of memory? Images take up a lot of memory... How big are your images?

Comment: 320x480 Png. Background is transparent and actual image size inside is about 150x150. Each image is about 8 Bytes. Yes, I faced before similar problem with [UIImage imageNamed:] It was not releasing at all, even AllocationsInstrument showed

Comment: If I had not these two images I would not be able to launch the application at all. So, problem is not there(

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is here? Instruments should tell you which objects are still in memory.

Comment: Because application has 5 similar UIImageViews that contains 30 images for animation. And a video ~3 Mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try and wrap a `NSAutoreleasePool` in your `for {}` function. I had the same memory problem by creating a huge 86000 size object array. I don't know why it sometimes don't release as it should.

Comment: As with autoreleased objects, they are released *somewhen* later... If you do a lot of stuff on the current "runloop iteration", it sums up pretty fast. A dedicated pool is a shortcut for this. But as the images are needed here anyway (they should be visible), there shouldn't be a big difference.

Comment: I have asked similar question about 2 months ago and in the previous question there was also such advice

Comment: but he calls [img release]; and I had the same. I have released the objects but they still existed as visible in Instruments

Comment: And this fixed your problem?!

Comment: as I said, there are some strange behaviors with release :D

Answer (score 1):

Memory management seems ok here.

Are you sure you have images from 0 ... 30, that is 31 in total and not 30 as your code suggests in the array allocation.

As for size, 31 images will take 320 * 480 * 4 * 31 = 19046400 bytes, which requires roughly 18 MB minimum.

Edit: if you have 5 of those, we are probably talking 80+ MB!

Comment: Yes, plus Video and application result in a crash. Will try to use AutoReleasePools

Comment: didn't he say that only the background image is 320x480 and the rest 150x150? and are they really that much memory if each image only has a size of 8byte?

Comment: I think you are misguided by the filesize of the images. This is *not* what it will look like when loaded. A single of those images will consume 600 kB.

Comment: @iPortable: Hmm... not sure. Thought they were 320*480 with transparent regions except some 150*150 region. But may be not. :-)

Comment: If I would remove the transparent region and leave only 150x150 will it affect somehow on the volume of each image?

Comment: Yes, in memory each pixel takes 4 bytes, no matter if transparent or not.

Comment: 4 bytes per pixel! Each image has 153600 of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 31 NSImages. If picture0.png or picture30.png do not exist in your bundle you may have a problem.

Try it with i+=5 or i+=10 to see if that fixes the problem.